# Facebook null GraphObject

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have been stuck with facebook implementation for days. I was getting this error no matter how I tried to post to wall:

```
Response: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

So I created a new android project and new project on facebook, followed all facebook tutorials for android, when I finally managed to post to my wall with no problem. Response then looked like this:

```
Response: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

In the new project I have created class that encapsulated all needed functionality to run facebook with no problems.

Then I moved that class to my old project, changed app_id to point to my new facebook application. But yet again:

```
Response: {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: -1, errorCode: -1, errorType: null, errorMessage: null}, isFromCache:false}
```

I updated package name and mainactivity class in facebook settings to point to old project. But that didn't do anything, new project still works without any problems and old one doesn't work.

What might be wrong?

**[EDIT]** P.S. Login and information retrieval about user and his friends works fine on both programs.

Comment: I also had this problem. In my case was because the publish action toke place without the needed permissions (even if the check in the activity was OK). Try to check the permissions directly from the applications setting on your Facebook account.

Comment: In my application. Under Settings->Permissions->User & Friend permissions I have added publish_actions. Nothing more. And I use same user account (admin account) to test those apps. Apps use same hash key and id. But only one works (the newer one).

Comment: I meant to check the permissions not from the app settings, but from the user settings (your common Facebook account, if you are trying to post on your own wall). Also I noticed that _getGraphObject_ return null if we try to send the same message sequentially. However it's always useful to use this _FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after recreating my old project bit by bit on the new one, I found one solution. On my new project I had this line in onCreate():

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

After removing this, my code stops working. And with this code, my old project now works fine and posts to wall. Though I still don't quite understand how this works. I do use my FB session in different threads, but they are executed one after another (one in one window, on login, another in other window, where I publish), so they are not running at the same time.

It still leaves me some questions.
Why does enabling problem checking causes me to be unable to post to my FB wall?
Is it okay to leave this code during development and in release?